# The Fastest Way-A Challenge

Tags: chess, optimization, retrograde-analysis, construction

This is my first “find the fastest way to this position” chess puzzle” here on PSE. However, this is not for just some random position. Let me explain.

Tim Krabbe has said on his site ([Journal Entry 387](https://timkr.home.xs4all.nl/chess2/diary.htm)), that the record, at least in 2013 for the most mutual consecutive checks is 54. He says that a proof game was sent to him, but I cannot find the game anywhere. This makes this a special question, because this is not only for a puzzle, but for practical purposes as well.

What is the fastest way to reach this postion?

**Alexey Khayhan, Tim Krabbe’s Website 2013, 54 consecutive checks**

[image]

FEN-5q2/2q1pn1B/R1Q1R3/1B2r1B1/1q1k1Knq/rr5Q/B2NPN1N/3Qb1QQ w - - 01

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to contact with Bader Al-Hajiri, a famous chess composer who's favorite genre is retrograde analysis. He is perhaps best known for his retro problems and compositions on Tim Krabbe's site. It turns out that he had actually composed a proof game for Krabbe's site back in 2013, but it was never published! I privately messaged him, and he agreed to have his original proof game published on this site.

Without further ado, Khanyan's position can be reached in **59 moves!**

**Bader Al-Hajiri,  Created On 9/22/2013, Original For Puzzling Stack Exchange On 8/24/2020**

> 1. b4 a5 2. bxa5 b5 3. h4 b4 4. h5 b3 5. h6 b2 6. hxg7 d5 7. a4 Bf5 8. f4 Kd7
>    9. c4 Kd6 10. Rh6+ Kc5 11. cxd5 Bg6 12. f5 Nf6 13. fxg6 Ng4 14. g8=B f5 15. d6 Nc6 16. a6 Rb8 17. a7 f4 18. a5 Rb3 19. a6 Bg7 20. a8=Q Bc3 21. a7 Nce5 22. Ra6 Ra3 23. Ba2 Kb5 24. g7 Qc8 25. Re6 h5 26. d7 h4 27. d8=Q h3 28. Qd3+ Kc5 29. g8=B h2 30. Nf3 h1=Q 31. Bh7 Qh5 32. Nh2 Nf6 33. Qh3 f3 34. Kf2 Kb5 35. d4 c5 36. g4 c4 37. g5 Nf7 38. g6 Bb4 39. Bg5 c3 40. Kg3 f2 41. Bg2 f1=Q 42. d5 Qg1 43. d6 Qb6 44. d7 c2+ 45. Kf4 Be1 46. d8=Q c1=Q+ 47. Nd2 b1=R 48. Qd4 Rd8 49. Qg1 Rd5 50. g7 Re5 51. g8=N Q1c3 52. Nh6 Rbb3 53. N6g4 Qf8 54. Nf2 Kc5 55. Bc6 Kd4 56. Bb5 Qbc7 57. Qah1 Qb4 58. a8=Q Ng4 59. Qac6 Qh4

Answer (score 2):

Far from optimal, I think, but here it is in **84** moves

> 1. c4 d5 
>  2. cxd5 g5 
>  3. h3 g4 
>  4. b4 g3 
>  5. a4 a5 
>  6. bxa5 Bg4 
>  7. hxg4 f5 
>  8. d4 f4 
>  9. g5 f3 
>  10. gxf3 Ra6 
>  11. f4 Rb6 
>  12. a6 Rb3 
>  13. Rh6 b5 
>  14. Rf6 h5 
>  15. a7 h4 
>  16. a5 h3 
>  17. a6 h2 
>  18. a8=Q h1=Q 
>  19. d6 Qh4 
>  20. Qh1 g2 
>  21. Nf3 c5 
>  22. Qh3 g1=R 
>  23. Nh2 b4 
>  24. a7 Rgg3 
>  25. g6 Nh6 
>  26. a8=B c4 
>  27. Ra6 Ra3 
>  28. Re6 c3 
>  29. Bd5 Nd7 
>  30. Ba2 Ne5 
>  31. f5 b3 
>  32. g7 c2 
>  33. g8=B Neg4 
>  34. f6 Bg7 
>  35. d5 Kd7 
>  36. f7 Qc7 
>  37. f8=Q Qb6 
>  38. Qf3 Ke8 
>  39. Qh1 b2 
>  40. f4 Qc7 
>  41. Bg2 Qb6 
>  42. d7+ Kf8 
>  43. d6 Qc7 
>  44. Bc6 Qb6 
>  45. Kf1 Rgb3 
>  46. Kg2 Qc7 
>  47. Be3 c1=Q 
>  48. Kf3 Qc3 
>  49. f5 Qb6 
>  50. d8=N Qc7 
>  51. Bb5 Qb6 
>  52. Nc6 Ke8 
>  53. f6 Qb4 
>  54. f7+ Kd7 
>  55. f8=Q Qc7 
>  56. Qf4 Nf7 
>  57. Qfg3 Bc3 
>  58. Qgg1 Rh5 
>  59. Bh7 Re5 
>  60. Bg5 Ke8 
>  61. d7+ Kf8 
>  62. Nd4 Kg7 
>  63. d8=Q Qb6 
>  64. Bf6+ Kh6 
>  65. Bg7+ Kg5 
>  66. Kg2 Kf4 
>  67. Kf1 Kg5 
>  68. Qc7 Kf4 
>  69. Bg8 Q6c5 
>  70. Kg2 Ke4 
>  71. Ndf3 Qb6 
>  72. Ne1 Q6c5 
>  73. Nd3 Qb6 
>  74. Qc8 Be1 
>  75. Qf1 Kd4 
>  76. Nd2 b1=Q 
>  77. Nf2 Qd8 
>  78. Qfg1 Ne3+ 
>  79. Kf3 Ng4+ 
>  80. Kf4 Qf8 
>  81. Bh6 Qc1 
>  82. Bh7 Qcc5 
>  83. Qcc6 Qd6 
>  84. Bg5 Qc7 *

Link to the game

> [check-54 setup](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=c4_d5_cxd5_g5_h3_g4_b4_g3_a4_a5_bxa5_Bg4_hxg4_f5_d4_f4_g5_f3_gxf3_Ra6_f4_Rb6_a6_Rb3_Rh6_b5_Rf6_h5_a7_h4_a5_h3_a6_h2_a8ZQ_h1ZQ_d6_Qh4_Qh1_g2_Nf3_c5_Qh3_g1ZR_Nh2_b4_a7_Rgg3_g6_Nh6_a8ZB_c4_Ra6_Ra3_Re6_c3_Bd5_Nd7_Ba2_Ne5_f5_b3_g7_c2_g8ZB_Neg4_f6_Bg7_d5_Kd7_f7_Qc7_f8ZQ_Qb6_Qf3_Ke8_Qh1_b2_f4_Qc7_Bg2_Qb6_d7*_Kf8_d6_Qc7_Bc6_Qb6_Kf1_Rgb3_Kg2_Qc7_Be3_c1ZQ_Kf3_Qc3_f5_Qb6_d8ZN_Qc7_Bb5_Qb6_Nc6_Ke8_f6_Qb4_f7*_Kd7_f8ZQ_Qc7_Qf4_Nf7_Qfg3_Bc3_Qgg1_Rh5_Bh7_Re5_Bg5_Ke8_d7*_Kf8_Nd4_Kg7_d8ZQ_Qb6_Bf6*_Kh6_Bg7*_Kg5_Kg2_Kf4_Kf1_Kg5_Qc7_Kf4_Bg8_Q6c5_Kg2_Ke4_Ndf3_Qb6_Ne1_Q6c5_Nd3_Qb6_Qc8_Be1_Qf1_Kd4_Nd2_b1ZQ_Nf2_Qd8_Qfg1_Ne3*_Kf3_Ng4*_Kf4_Qf8_Bh6_Qc1_Bh7_Qcc5_Qcc6_Qd6_Bg5_Qc7)